How to write test file for count down timer react component in jest?
I tried to write the test for the countdown file using jest
This is my countdown file:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import _padStart from 'lodash/padStart'
import styles from './CountDown.module.scss'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import duration from 'dayjs/plugin/duration' // Import the duration plugin
import cx from 'classnames'
import useCountDown from '../utils/useCountDown'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { twMerge } from 'tailwind-merge'

dayjs.extend(duration) // Extend dayjs with the duration plugin

const worker_script = dynamic(
    () => import('utils').then((mod) => mod.timerWorker),
    { ssr: false }
)

const CountDown = ({ startTime, containerClassName, onCompleteTimer }) => {
    const [lectureStartWorker, setLectureStartWorker] = useState(null)
    const [timerData, setTimerData] = useState({
        day: 0,
        hour: 0,
        minute: 0,
    })
    const [showCountDown, setShowCountdown] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        setLectureStartWorker(new Worker(worker_script))

        return () => {
            lectureStartWorker?.postMessage({
                action: 'stop',
                payload: null,
            })
            lectureStartWorker?.terminate?.()
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!lectureStartWorker) return
        if (startTime) {
            const currentTime = dayjs(new Date())
            const _startTime = dayjs(startTime)

            const duration = _startTime.diff(currentTime, 'seconds')
            if (duration >= 0) handleLectureStartTimer(duration * 1000)
        }
    }, [lectureStartWorker, startTime])

    useEffect(() => {
        const { day, hour, minute } = timerData
        if (day || hour || minute) {
            setShowCountdown(true)
        } else {
            setShowCountdown(false)
            onCompleteTimer && onCompleteTimer()
        }
    }, [timerData])

    const handleLectureStartTimer = (duration) => {
        handleCountdown(duration)
        lectureStartWorker &&
            lectureStartWorker.postMessage({
                action: 'start',
                payload: {
                    interval: 1000 * 60,
                    duration: duration,
                },
            })
        lectureStartWorker.onmessage = (event) => {
            let timeLeft = event.data || 0
            handleCountdown(timeLeft)
        }
    }

    const handleCountdown = (timeLeft) => {
        const _data = dayjs.duration(timeLeft)
        setTimerData({
            day: parseInt(_data.asDays()),
            hour: _data.hours(),
            minute: _data.minutes(),
        })
    }

    return (
        showCountDown && (
            <div className={twMerge(cx(styles.container, containerClassName))}>
                <div className={styles.textDiv}>Class starts in</div>
                <div className={styles.timeContainer}>
                    <div className={styles.timeDiv}>
                        <span role="timer" aria-label="days">
                            {timerData.day ? _padStart(timerData.day, 2, 0) : '00'}
                        </span>
                        <span>:</span>
                        <span role="timer" aria-label="hours">
                            {timerData.hour ? _padStart(timerData.hour, 2, 0) : '00'}
                        </span>
                        <span>:</span>
                        <span role="timer" aria-label="minutes">
                            {timerData.minute ? _padStart(timerData.minute, 2, 0) : '00'}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.timeLabelDiv}>
                        <span className={styles.daysLabel}>Days</span>
                        <span className={styles.hoursLabel}>Hrs</span>
                        <span className={styles.minutesLabel}>Mins</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    )
}

export default CountDown

And the timerworker.js file as below (this is the web worker script) :
const timerWorker = () => {
    let timerStart = false
    let intervalId = null
    let timeLeft = 0
    self.onmessage = (e) => {
        const { data = {} } = e
        const { action, payload } = data
        switch (action) {
            case 'start':
                start(payload)
                break
            case 'stop':
                stop()
                break
            default:
                self.postMessage('please pass a valid action')
                break
        }
    }

    function start(payload) {
        const { interval = 1000, duration = 0 } = payload
        stop()
        timeLeft = duration
        if (duration >= 0) self.postMessage(timeLeft)
        intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            timeLeft -= interval
            if (timeLeft <= 0) {
                stop()
            } else {
                self.postMessage(timeLeft)
            }
        }, interval)
        timerStart = true
    }

    function stop() {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
        timerStart = false
        timeLeft = 0
        self.postMessage(timeLeft)
    }
}

let code = timerWorker.toString()
code = code.substring(code.indexOf('{') + 1, code.lastIndexOf('}'))

const blob =
    typeof Blob !== 'undefined'
        ? new Blob([code], { type: 'application/javascript' })
        : {}
const worker_script =
    typeof Blob !== 'undefined' ? URL.createObjectURL(blob) : {}

export default worker_script

I have tried writing this test case and it runs :
import React from 'react'
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react'
import CountDown from './CountDown'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

// Mock the dynamic import for the worker script
jest.mock('next/dynamic', () => () => jest.fn())

// Mock the worker constructor
class MockWorker {
    constructor() {
        this.onmessage = null
    }
    postMessage(message) {
        // Simulating the worker behavior based on the action
        if (message.action === 'start') {
            const duration = message.payload.duration
            let timeLeft = duration

            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                if (timeLeft <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(interval)
                    this.onmessage({ data: 0 }) 
                } else {
                    timeLeft -= message.payload.interval
                    this.onmessage({ data: timeLeft }) // Post the remaining time
                }
            }, message.payload.interval)
        }

        if (message.action === 'stop') {
            this.onmessage({ data: 0 }) 
        }
    }

    terminate() {
        // Mock terminate
    }
}

describe('CountDown Component', () => {
    const mockStartTime = dayjs().add(1, 'hour').toISOString()

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks()
        global.Worker = MockWorker // Overriding global Worker with mock
        jest.useFakeTimers() 
    })

    test('renders countdown component with initial values', () => {
        render(<CountDown startTime={mockStartTime} />)

        // Check for initial timer labels 
        expect(screen.getByRole('timer', { name: 'days' })).toHaveTextContent('00')
        expect(screen.getByRole('timer', { name: 'hours' })).toHaveTextContent('00')
        expect(screen.getByRole('timer', { name: 'minutes' })).toHaveTextContent('59')
    })

    test('updates time left as the countdown progresses', async () => {
        render(<CountDown startTime={mockStartTime} />)

        // Fast-forward by 30 minutes
        act(() => {
            jest.advanceTimersByTime(30 * 60 * 1000) // 30 minutes
        })

        //Expected results after 30 minutes have passed
        expect(screen.getByRole('timer', { name: 'hours' })).toHaveTextContent('00')
        expect(screen.getByRole('timer', { name: 'minutes' })).toHaveTextContent('29')
    })
})

But I don't want to use class based code and dont want to mock a new function I want to see the component rendering when it uses the timerworker.js file as web worker and renders the time.
